# What do those different symbols on achievements mean?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

When I look at achievements, some of them have additional symbols next to the "achievement points".

[image: The achievement row for Spirit Guide: Complete Act IV with a Witch Doctor on Normal difficulty. Has the symbols on the right highlighted: a star and a 2, a plus sign, and the number 10 in a larger font.]

I know the 10 is the number of "points" (though I have no idea what those points are for).  But what do the cross symbol and the star with the 2 next to it mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: Star 6] means that the achievement has 6 rewards for completeing its various stages.

[image: Plus] [image: Minus] Is the collapsed/expanded state of the achievement. If this icon is absent, the achievement cannot be expanded.

[image: Achievement Points] means that this achievement is worth 10 points.

Achievement "Points" are an arbitrary number by which you can measure your awesomeness. Nearly all achievements are worth 10 points, regardless of their difficulty.

The one notable exception to this rule is "meta-achievements", the criteria for which are to complete a group of *other* achievements that are typically related to one another. These are usually worth more than 10 points.

Comment: I assume "points" is just supposed to be a measure of the relative difficulty of an achievement?  So you can add up the total points for two profiles and see who has done more?

Comment: @bwarner Not exactly, and yes. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Cross means you can expand the achievement and see more details.