# What are the stars on some Diablo 3 achievements?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do those different symbols on achievements mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66516/what-do-those-different-symbols-on-achievements-mean)

Some of the achievements in Diablo 3 have a star on them with a 1 next to it. What does that signify?

Comment: The number of rewards earned by completing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It signifies that you gain a reward from completing the achievement, meaning you get new designs for your banner. The number is how many rewards are available for that achievement, so for boss achievements where the achievement has a reward for each difficulty you will see a star with 4 next to it.

Comment: Oh, okay! Hadn't caught that correlation before. Thanks!