# Star Next to Achievement

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do those different symbols on achievements mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66516/what-do-those-different-symbols-on-achievements-mean)

What are the stars with the numbers by them on the achievements panel?  Is this how many of my RealID friends have completed the achievement?  It seems like it is, but looking through the achievements, it seems like some of them should have been completed by more people, so I'm not sure.

[image: Cropped screenshot of the achievement screen; highlighted are a star and the number six on the row for the Moneybags achievement (Pick up 100,000 gold) and a star and the number 1 on the row for The Comfort of Strangers achievement (Recruit the Templar, Scoundrel, and Enchantress).]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some achievements give you decorations for your banner for completing them and that star indicates how many rewards that achievement gives you. Some achievement are "tiered"(good example: the pick up x gold achievements), which is why some will have 6 stars, because multiple achievements in that set give awards.